# What material is this?

Tags: material-selection, sewing

[image: stuffed reindeer]
What material is this stuffed toy I finished today made from? I want to know in case I want to duplicate it later and I’m not sure if I’ll be able to find the pattern again.

I’ve got 2 more patterns pretty much like it back in my sewing space, but that’s it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Recycled Wool Felt

It looks like.

[image]

Original image from [www.360felt.com](https://www.360felt.com/products/colored-wool-felt/)